# oracle setup in solaris

Tags: oracle, unix

I am running a batch job which schedules a shell script in solaris. 
Each of the scripts have oracle environment variables, such as oracle_home, path, library set within first few lines to run the queries in the script. 
Is there any way to automatically get the oracle path picked up when the scripts run?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly... You can use oraenv to set the oracle environment.

Here is a basic example:

```
#!/bin/bash
ORACLE_SID=orcl

. oraenv << EOF >> /dev/null
$ORACLE_SID
EOF

echo $ORACLE_SID
echo $ORACLE_HOME
echo $ORACLE_BASE
echo $PATH
```

This script gets the Oracle related paths and environment automatically from the oratab.

Please not that oraenv is normally located in /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin.

Comment: Yep, standard stuff. Note also the ORAENV_ASK variable used to control the behaviour of oraenv in these non-interactive scripts.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your solution. i tried the above. But it doesnt give proper values for oracle_home/ path. For oracle_base, it prints nothing. For oracle_home, it gives wrong value. Can you please suggest if i am missing something here.

Comment: Could you post your oratab file? It's located in /etc/oratab or /var/opt/oracle/oratab.